# React: Passing input validation message from child component to parent form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Forgive me I've been through a lot of the existing questions around on this topic without success.

I have a filter dialog with several input fields (child components) and a submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled if a validation message exists on one of the child components.

Child (simplified):

```
const TextSearch: FC<TextSearchProps> = memo((props) => {

  const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] =  useState('')

  const onTextChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const input = e.currentTarget.value

    if(input && !checkNumericOnly(input)) {
      setValidationMessage('Only numbers allowed')
    } else {
      setValidationMessage('')
    }

return (
  <div className={classes.textSearch}>
    <InputText
      className={validationMessage ? 'p-invalid' : ''}
      onChange={onTextChange}
    />
    <div className={classes.invalid}>{validationMessage}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Parent:

```
const AdvancedSearch: FC<SearchProps> = memo(_props => {
    const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch()

    const data = useSelector(selectSearchData())

    const [validInput, setValidInput] = useState(true) // this is what I'm trying to set
```

How do I `setValidInput` based on whether the child `validationMessage` is true?

Have tried a function in the parent dialog:

```
function handleValidInput(valid: boolean) {
    setValidInput(valid)
}
```

But have not been able to figure out how to call it from the child.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your setState function to your children and then update the state there:

In parent (AdvancedSearch):

```js
const [validInput, setValidInput] = useState(true);
```

```js
return (
  <TextSearch setValidInput={setValidInput} />
)
```

In child (TextSearch):

```js
const onTextChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const input = e.currentTarget.value
  if(input && !checkNumericOnly(input)) {
    setValidationMessage('Only numbers allowed');
    props.setValidInput(false);
  } else {
    setValidationMessage('');
    props.setValidInput(true);
  }
}
```

```js
return (
  <div className={classes.textSearch}>
    <InputText
      className={validationMessage ? 'p-invalid' : ''}
      onChange={onTextChange}
    />
    <div className={classes.invalid}>{validationMessage}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.

Does the <InputText> element have to be moved to the parent? I have several different child components that are all search/filter fields.

Also I have a ```TS2552: Cannot find name 'onTextChange'. Did you mean 'onchange'?``` error with line 5 of the suggested parent.

Comment: You're welcome. Please pick my answer as the correct answer if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find a way to make your solution work unfortunately :(

Comment: Can someone explain to me how the child can have a onTextChange method without returning an <InputText> element. What would the child return in the suggested solution? Thanks.

Comment: @melable Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer. Please test the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @Amirhossein. On the parent I am getting error ``` Property 'setValidInput' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextSearchProps' ``` and on the child I am getting ```TS2339: Property 'setValidInput' does not exist on type 'TextSearchProps'```. Do I need to specify ```setValidInput``` as a <TextSearchProps> property? ( I didn't think that was valid for child to parent )

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you should add it to your TextSearchProps.